# Why would clicking on one element to trigger an event stop another from working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, button

I currently have a set up like the following jsfiddle. I'm not great with javascript so I've managed to put together some code that tells one button to slide the 'wrapper' down from the top and the other button to slide the wrapper up from the bottom.

As it stands if you click the 'description-button' first this event works fine. As soon as you click the 'contact-button' and then go to click the 'description-button' the 'description-button' no longer works.

The same thing applies if you click the 'contact-button' first straight after load and go to click the 'description-button' sec on - it no longer works.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9qKrB/2/)

JS

```
var clicked=false;
$(".contact-button").on('click', function(){
if(clicked)
{

clicked=false;
$(".wrapper").css({"top": "0px", "-webkit-transition": "top 0.5s ease-in-out", "-moz-
transition": "top 0.5s ease-in-out", "-o-transition": "top 0.5s ease-in-out", "-ms-
transition": "top 0.5s ease-in-out", "transition": "top 0.5s ease-in-out"});
}
else
{

clicked=true;
$(".wrapper").css({"top": "100px", "-webkit-transition": "top 0.5s ease-in-out", "-moz-
transition": "top 0.5s ease-in-out", "-o-transition": "top 0.5s ease-in-out", "-ms-
transition": "top 0.5s ease-in-out", "transition": "top 0.5s ease-in-out"});
}

});


var clicked=true;
$(".description-button").on('click', function(){

if(clicked)
{

clicked=false;
$(".wrapper").css({"bottom": "100px", "-webkit-transition": "bottom 0.5s ease-in-out", "-
moz-transition": "bottom 0.5s ease-in-out", "-o-transition": "bottom 0.5s ease-in-out", "-
ms-transition": "bottom 0.5s ease-in-out", "transition": "bottom 0.5s ease-in-out"});

}
else
{

clicked=true;
$(".wrapper").css({"bottom": "0px", "-webkit-transition": "bottom 0.5s ease-in-out", "-    
moz-transition": "bottom 0.5s ease-in-out", "-o-transition": "bottom 0.5s ease-in-out", "-
ms-transition": "bottom 0.5s ease-in-out", "transition": "bottom 0.5s ease-in-out"});
}

});
```

If anyone could point out or explain why this might be happening I would be really grateful.

Thanks!

Comment: You are using `var clicked` twice. So in the end, `clicked` in both functions will start with being `true`.

Comment: Ok so how would I go about rectifying my current code so that one doesn't cancel the other out?

Comment: Is there something simple that I could implement to be able to use multiple clicks?

Comment: Simply give the second `clicked` another name.

Comment: Just tried changing clicked to tapped and that doesn't seem to work. http://jsfiddle.net/4U3yT/1/ Have I understood you correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9qKrB/9/).. its working fine

```
$(".contact-button").on('click', function(){
   var clicked = $('#cont').attr('data-state');

    if(clicked=='true')
    {
        $('#cont').attr('data-state','false');
        alert($('#cont').attr('data-state'));
        $(".wrapper").css({"top": "100px", "-webkit-transition": "top 0.5s ease-in-out", "-moz-transition": "top 0.5s ease-in-out", "-o-transition": "top 0.5s ease-in-out", "-ms-transition": "top 0.5s ease-in-out", "transition": "top 0.5s ease-in-out"});
    }else if(clicked=='false')
    {
        $('#cont').attr('data-state','true');
          alert($('#cont').attr('data-state'));
         
        $(".wrapper").css({"top": "0px", "-webkit-transition": "top 0.5s ease-in-out", "-moz-transition": "top 0.5s ease-in-out", "-o-transition": "top 0.5s ease-in-out", "-ms-transition": "top 0.5s ease-in-out", "transition": "top 0.5s ease-in-out"});
    }
});



$(".description-button").on('click', function(){
    var clic = $('#des').attr('data-statee');
    if(clic =='true')
    {
          $('#des').attr('data-statee','false');
        alert($('#des').attr('data-statee'));
        $(".wrapper").css({"top": "-100px"});
    }
    if(clic =='false')
    {
        $('#des').attr('data-statee','true');
          alert($('#des').attr('data-statee'));
        $(".wrapper").css({"top": "0px"});
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response I was implementing that into my website and it works perfectly. Thank you for taking the time to do that :)